# How to access Appmaker Revision ID?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'd like to access the Revision ID for my appmaker app so I can display it inside the app somewhere. This is the ID in Settings > Revisions.

How can I programatically access Revision ID?

Answer (score 0):

At this time App Maker doesn't provide API to get app's revision in runtime, but I believe there should be a feature request for it. Meanwhile the only way to get deployment's revision is through [Deployment Settings](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment#deployment_settings):

[image: Deployment Settings]

Answer (score 0):

An app's revision ID can be accessed server side like this:

```
function getRevisionId() {
  return app.a.a.a[36].c.revision;
}
```